stdinというエラーが分からない
stdin line ~~　というエラーの直し方がわかりません。
exit()も試してみたのですが直りませんでした。勉強始めたばかりで何が何なのかわからず困っています。助けてください。


質問・タイトルとして現在記述されている内容だと何が問題なのかどう助言・回答すれば良いのか情報が無いに等しいです。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問記事を編集して対象のソースコード・作業/実行している環境や状況・発生したエラーメッセージ等について詳細な情報を表示されたまま略さずにテキストで提示してください。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, XY問題, スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

「stdinというエラーが分からない」とのことですが、エラーは「stdinというエラー」ではなくてIndentationErrorですね。インデントに問題があるとのメッセージなのでコードのインデントを見直されてはいかがでしょうか？

先ずは発生している現象がどのような状況であるかを把握しましょう。

提示されているのはVSCodeの画面ですね。
質問の対象は約3つに分かれたVSCode画面の右下側ウインドウにある「ターミナル」タブに表示された内容についてでしょう。
「ターミナル」タブではVSCode画面の他のウインドウ(編集しているファイルやその内容)との関連・連携は無く、Pythonインタプリタが対話モードで起動されていて、それに対するコンソールからの入出力が行われています。
Pythonインタプリタにとって「コンソールからの入出力」というのは stdin(標準入力), stdout(標準出力), stderr(標準エラー出力) というファイルとの入出力を指します。
質問の「stdin」というのは、  File "<stdin>", line 2と表示されたエラーメッセージの一部であり、エラーそのものではなく、エラーが発生したファイル名を示しています。残りのline 2はエラーが発生した行位置を示しています。
実際に発生しているエラーは merino さんがコメントで指摘しているようにIndentationError: expected an indented block after 'while' statement on line 1のことです。翻訳するとIndentationError: 「while」ステートメント後の1行目にインデントされたブロックが必要ですとなります。
そのメッセージの直前の行に^と表示されているのが、該当の行の中でエラーが発生(or検出)した桁位置を示しています。

何が問題であったのか？ということですが、原因および対処は以下になります。

「while」ステートメントの後で、whileループ内の処理であることを示すインデント(空白やタブで字下げすること)が必要なのに、それが行われずに単に行の先頭の何も入力していない状態でEnterキーを押して改行したからですね。
それの区別を示すのが各行の先頭に表示されているプロンプト文字で、>>> と... で区別されます。while(やif,forあるいはclass,defなど)を入力した次の行で... のプロンプトが現れた場合にはインデント(空白やタブで字下げする)入力が必要になります。2.1.2. 対話モードを参照してください。

状況は少し違いますが、こちらの質問も類似の内容ですので参考にしてください。
for 文を含むコードでエラー: IndentationError: expected an indented block
